PHP ERROR! symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2: undefined symbol: ucnv_close_74
Im using ubuntu server and after one apt dist-upgrade my nginx stop working! I got the error:
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)

So, i I started to investigate and open the var/log/nginx

connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream
2. okay. thats a PHP problem - not nginx. So, i start to verify and start "php" on the shell, and the return is:
php: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2: undefined symbol: ucnv_close_74
And ends the process.
3. I have tried to reinstall the libxml2 and PHP with apt-get --reinstall but the error continues...

What version of Ubuntu? What version of PHP?
